# Prepared Statement and Phpmyadmin output different result in PHP Version 7.1.1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Let's say I have this table

```
follower_user_id  |  following_user_id
1                 |  2
1                 |  3
```

The goal is to get a number of the followed by "user_id 1" and at the same time, a number of users who follow "user_id 1".
So it should display that
followed by user1 is  2 
and 
0 users follow user 1.

This is my code:

```
    $user_id = 1;
    $check_follows = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(`following_user_id`) FROM followings 
WHERE `follower_user_id` = ?) AS follows, (SELECT COUNT(`follower_user_id`) 
FROM followings WHERE `following_user_id` = ?) AS followedby"; 
    $stmt_follows = $connection->prepare($check_follows); 
    $stmt_follows->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $user_id);
    $stmt_follows->execute(); 
    $stmt_follows->store_result(); 
    if($stmt_follows) {  
    $stmt_follows->bind_result($followings, $follows);
    echo $followings . " - " . $follows;
          }
    else{ echo "Error"; }
```

in Phpmyadmin, this query outputs correctly

```
follows | followed_by
2       | 0
```

While PHP outputs none of them even Error.
When I put

```
 $result23 = $stmt_follows ->get_result();
 var_dump($result23);
```

this displayed: bool(false)

Could you please tell me what is the issue? I'm running this script on Xampp with PHP Version 7.1.1.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling `store_result()` without saving that to a variable?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I moved store_result() after binding. But still no output. I think I miss something.